# Detecting C2 traffic over DNS?

Tags: dns, detection

Let's assume I have a large enterprise network (thousands of nodes) and somewhere on that network there is malware communicating over DNS for C2.  Let's assume the requests are designed such that the traffic is legitimate DNS and doesn't contain obvious commands or other strings that can be trivially detected.  (Maybe it uses A records or AAAA to encode the data.)

It's possible to try to detect the traffic using several techniques:

1. Look for regularly timed DNS traffic.  (i.e., exactly every hour)
2. Look for *infrequently* requested domains -- on a network this large, the malware requests should be the outliers.  (But perhaps there's other traffic that's an outlier as well.)
3. Look for DNS results that keep changing (but maybe it's DNS load balancing)

Are there other techniques I have not considered?

Comment: Looking for a list? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Most malware that abuses channels (from my experience) includes some form of randomisation in connection timing. Even something as simple as `60 minutes + rand(-5,5)` can defeat timing profilers. You will also find that people have some shockingly regular patterns in their browsing habits.
2. From experience, frequency analysis will produce a lot of false positives in a large enterprise. Everyone's into their own thing and interests shift. Instead, analyse the domains for "infancy". Look up when the domain was registered and look for domains less than 3 months old. Then look for domains not owned by a `* Inc.` or `* Ltd.` or who have a "domain privacy shield" in place. Bubble those up for further investigation.

One thing you have not mentioned is comparing the domain with blacklists from a blacklist service. I assume you thought of that, but I wanted to mention it.

Remember that it is trivial for malware authors to adjust to any detection methods that you can devise (like timing analysis). The more robust detection processes require complex statistical analysis on both the destination and the requesting node compared the node's peers and general trends in the local environment (timing, time, frequency, content, bandwidth, mismatched peer profiles (a non-peer acting like a peer)). And even then, it will require further analysis to determine the true positives.

I have developed UEBA algorithms for just this sort of thing, and once you start, you will find yourself down a bit of a rabbit hole ("maybe I can tweak it this way and get better efficiency!"). For 80% effectiveness, focus on the "infancy" analysis that I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a lot more to think about.  It's amazing how trivial it is to make the analysis that much more complex!

Answer (score 2):

Two other options:

1) Monitor the length of the DNS queries. C2 traffic, especially if exfiltrating data, is likely to have larger queries. If tracked over time this might show a possible tunnel

2) FQDN count by [second-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain).

> Some of the specific payload analysis rules could be bypassed by a
>   knowledgeable attacker. They could shorten the labels used and reduce the number of
>   labels in an FQDN. However, they will always need to create a large number of unique
>   FQDNs which are normally from a specific root domain.

This is from a [SANS paper](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/dns/detecting-dns-tunneling-34152) on detecting DNS tunnels which also gives several other possible indicators and covers specifically this second point in great detail.

Comment: I assumed your first point was covered by his "legitimate DNS and doesn't contain obvious commands or other strings that can be trivially detected". Are you thinking differently?

Comment: I'm referring to just the size of the requests and replies, i.e. number of characters without regard to what they represent assuming they'll be encoded or encrypted. For example an A record request for `MRZGS3TLEBWW64TFEBXXMYLMORUW4ZI.t.example.com`

Comment: To me, that was covered by his preface (and the first thing to look for, anyway), but you're right that he did not specifically call that out.

Comment: The issue with FQDN count by 2-level domain is that you'll easily run in a lot of false positives, because CDNs. An example: "cs2-wac.apr-8315.edgecastdns.net". Go figure.

Comment: @ximaera but CDNs are well-known enough to be whitelisted, no? Even so, I still think the "infancy" analysis would prevent this false positive.

Comment: @schroeder not only there already are [no less than 100 popular CDNs](https://tinyurl.com/yc5blbbw) (not even mentioning smaller ones), but they get split, merged, renamed, etc. Large enterprises open their own delivery networks and then sell or shut down them at will. Also, their FQD naming in most cases is a complete mess. *Sometimes* you can use reverse DNS check to verify if something is a valid CDN node. Sometimes you can't. This is just a whole different world, and if you implement something close to FQDN counting, then either you're dealing with it or it's just asking for trouble.

Comment: @ximaera hmm - good to know that CDNs are still in the "Wild West" stage of development. Yeah, FQDN counting seems infeasible.